# SQL stored procdure using dates as parameters returning blank rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, blank-line

I am in desperate need of some help!

I am currently working on a project for SQL in a course I am doing (Due on Friday)

One of the questions is to create a stored procedure which shows dates of sales_orders within a certain range.

I have created the following stored procedure for this question, but all I am getting is blank rows? From what I can tell it seems to be reading the dates wrong, but I have no idea why? Can anyone please help? I am a newbie at SQL.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE customer_order_range (start_date DATE, end_date DATE)

BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM customer_order
WHERE `date` >= start_date 
AND `date` <= end_date;

END //

DELIMITER ;


CALL customer_order_range ( 'start_date' = '2020-02-01', 'end_date' = '2020-03-05');
```

It returns blank rows. My customer_order table has a date column, which is stored as a DATE value.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Conor

Comment: Single quotes around columns names is usually just wrong.

Comment: Date is a reserved word, try to find another name for that column? Also, what is the type of the date of sales column ?

Comment: Hi all, man thany thanks for your help. I'm using MyySQL.

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh I have switched the name of the column to "Order_date" thank you! . Also the type of date in the table I'm using is DATE, and it;s formatted like 2020-02-15 for example

Answer (score 1):

I've got it!

This piece of the code is wrong:

```
CALL customer_order_range ( 'start_date' = '2020-02-01', 'end_date' = '2020-03-05');
```

It should instead be:

```
CALL customer_order_range ('2020-02-01','2020-03-05');
```

The problem arose when I put the parameter names in with their values when calling the stored procedure. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the delimiters and the columns names like below :

```
CALL customer_order_range ('2020-02-01', '2020-03-05');
```

Comment: Thank you Sandra, I've tried it but I get this error message: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'start_date' in 'field list'. When I include the delimiters, it acftually works fine, just no rows are returned? It's very strange I think no?

Comment: Actually you don't need the column names, just put the values directly I updated the answer.